# Delete rows which is not match from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, split

**Src**

```
**************************
 EMPID     ENTERTAINMENT
 **************************
 101        BaseBall,Cricket
 102        Badminton,Chess
 103        Golf,Reading Books
 ************************************
```

Using delimiter `,` split the record and added it separate record into target table.

**Tgt**

```
**************************
 EMP_ID     ENTERTAINMENT
 **************************
 101        BaseBall
 101        Cricket
 102        Badminton
 102        Chess
 103        Golf
 103        Reading Books
**********************************
```

Delete rows which is not match from source to target table. I.e. if there is any changes happens in source table, need to replicate the same in target table as well.

**Expected Scenario Example :**

**Src**

```
**************************
 EMPID     ENTERTAINMENT
 **************************
 101        BaseBall
 102        Badminton
 103        Golf,Reading Books
 ************************************
```

**Tgt**

```
**************************
 EMP_ID     ENTERTAINMENT
 **************************
 101        BaseBall
 102        Badminton
 103        Golf
 103        Reading Books
**********************************
```

I have deleted 101 i.e. (101- Cricket) and 102 i.e. (102 -Chess) from target(Tgt) table since there is no data available in source table (Src) table.
Can anyone advise, how we can achieve using SQL query?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So you need to update table `Tgt` whenever table `Src` is changed, correct?

Comment: I answered your question as asked, but I don't understand why you want to do this. Why not just make TGT a view and leave it at that? As a view, it will automatically reflect any changes made to SRC.

Comment: @ScaryWombat : i tried via Stored procedure

Comment: @Abra : yes correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, test data for SRC:

```
create table src(empid, ENTERTAINMENT) as
select 101, 'BaseBall,Cricket' from dual union all
select 102, 'Badminton,Chess' from dual union all
select 103, 'Golf,Reading Books' from dual;
```

Now create a view that corresponds to what TGT should be:

```
create or replace view v_tgt as
select empid, x.entertainment
from src, xmltable(
  'if (contains($X,",")) then ora:tokenize($X,",") else $X'
  passing entertainment as X
  columns entertainment varchar2(64) path '.'
) x;
```

This is one of many methods to split strings. See https://stewashton.wordpress.com/category/splitting-strings/ for some of the others.

Now create the TGT table from the view:

```
create table tgt as select * from v_tgt;
```

Finally, here is a MERGE statement that will compare TGT to V_TGT and make TGT identical:

```
merge /*+ qb_name(SYNC_PARTITION) USE_NL(O) */ into (
  select /*+ qb_name(target) */
    "EMPID", "ENTERTAINMENT", rowid Z##RID
  from TGT
) O
using (
select /*+ qb_name(CDC_PARTITION) */ * from (
  select /*+ qb_name(before_filter) */
    "EMPID", "ENTERTAINMENT",
    case
      when Z##NEW = 1
        and sum(Z##NEW) over(partition by
          "EMPID", "ENTERTAINMENT"
        order by null rows unbounded preceding) > sum(Z##OLD) over(partition by
          "EMPID", "ENTERTAINMENT"
        )
        then 'I'
      when Z##OLD = 1
        and sum(Z##OLD) over(partition by
          "EMPID", "ENTERTAINMENT"
        order by null rows unbounded preceding) > sum(Z##NEW) over(partition by
          "EMPID", "ENTERTAINMENT"
        )
        then 'D'
    end Z##OP, Z##RID
  FROM (
    select /*+ qb_name(old) */
    "EMPID", "ENTERTAINMENT",
    1 Z##OLD, 0 Z##NEW, rowid Z##RID
    from TGT O
    union all
    select /*+ qb_name(new) */
    "EMPID", "ENTERTAINMENT",
    0, 1, null
    from v_tgt N
  )
)
where Z##OP is not null
) N
on (
  O.Z##RID = n.Z##RID
)
when matched then update set
  "EMPID"=N."EMPID"
  delete where N.Z##OP = 'D'
when not matched then insert (
  "EMPID", "ENTERTAINMENT"
) values(
  N."EMPID", N."ENTERTAINMENT"
);
```

I generated this MERGE statement using a tool I present here: https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2018/02/12/comp_sync-1-a-new-table-compare-sync-package/

Best regards,
Stew Ashton